# does the order of HTTP POST parameters master

Tags: php, http, post, http-post

I have a code that does HTTP post to a remote server with a set of parameters as shown belo.w

http://localhost:8085/setValue.php?ip=192.168.21.45&port=8089&version=1.0.0&area_id=9999&area_name="AreaName"

Is the above HTTP POST equivalent to the one below.

http://localhost:8085/setValue.php?ip=192.168.21.45&port=8089&area_id=9999&area_name="AreaName"&version=1.0.0

or are they different. The values that are passed are identical, only the order of parameters have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

In *general*, the answer to this question is that it **does not matter**.

99% of the time you will not be POSTing to endpoints that take the POST body as query parameters. If you do, you're [exposing yourself to man-in-the-middle attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url). **Please do not do this**. *Instead*, you should make use of `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Neither of these care about the order of POST arguments.

However, note that it's worth mentioning that you're using PHP in your example, which **does** care about **function** parameter order. Note that any defaults **must** be on the right side of any non-default arguments, or things won't work as expected.

For example, the following will throw `Missing argument 2 in call to makeyogurt()`:

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($type = "acidophilus", $flavour)
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}
 
echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // won't work as expected
?>
```

Whereas the following will succeed:

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($flavour, $type = "acidophilus")
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}
 
echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // works as expected
?>
```